# CSS Nintex disable spacebar no spaces in text input

Tags: css, nintex-workflow

In Nintex I am trying to limit bad data input by the user using CSS. The data needs to be in all caps, with no spaces. The all caps portion is easy via

```
.transformToAllCaps {text-transform: uppercase;}.
```

However, I have no idea how to not allow spaces. Can anyone help me out with this? Is this even possible in CSS? or would I need to use another setting in Nintex?

Comment: CSS generally cannot be used to validate or alter data. `text-transform` will change the way it is displayed on the screen, but the underlying text will still be mixed case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible with CSS, but you could remove the spaces from the string using JS:

```
str = str.replace(/\s/g, '');
```